# Wanted to automated mobile application

Tags: java

I'm trying to run a program, but it's showing an error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>
> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new
> remote session. Please check the server log for more details.
>
> Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the
> command. Original error: The application at
> 'C:\Users\Sodainmind\eclipse-workspace.metadata.metadata\Mobileautomation\carbonate_staging_1-75_23MAR2020.apk'
> does not exist or is not accessible

how to solve ? i have change work place of that application too but its not working

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: Hi I think it is better to show us your code . this error sims to be about selenium web driver but show code part which causes this error